# How to run a function after setState, tried useEffect with dependency but it failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I have two problems here, but let me show you my code first

```
const [error, setError] = useState({error: "", title : ""})
const formInitialState = {
  title :{
    value : '',
    maxLength : 15,
    required : true,
    valid : false,
    message : "Your meal has no name, please select a name"
  },
  description : {
    value : '',
    required : true,
    maxLength : 100,
    valid : false,
    message : "Pitch [description] is required"
  },
}
```

I am trying to show an error to the user when he tries to submit the form. I am using useReducer to manage the form state and actions but using useState to manage the error..

Here is the problem

```
const submitHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const isValid = checkValidity(formState);
  if (!isValid) {
    const wrongInput = Object.keys(formState).find((item) => !formState[item].valid);
    return setError({
      title: formState[wrongInput].title,
      error: formState[wrongInput].message,
    });
  }

  // do something if its valid...
};
```

what i want to achieve here is, when a user submits an invalid form it sets the error state to the error message and the set the showModal state [which toggles the modal visibility] to true. in the modal i get values from the error state and display it on the Modal,therefore i want setShowModal to run only when the setError has completed, i know better to add the code directly below it so i added it to useEffect with error as a dependency  but it still didn't work

```
useEffect(()=> setShowModal(true), [error])
```

In the react developer tools i can see clearly that the modal is called before the values reflect on the error state

Question 2 
Why does the useEffect run on load of the page even though i gave it an error dependency?
It sets my modal to true on initial load then waits for the error to change after that, how can i stop this?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Please, i want to appologize to you guys, I just found out the text was white in color so it blended with the background... yeah stupid I know :)

Answer (score 2):

`useEffect` is run each time its dependencies update, but also on the initial render. If you want the modal to be shown only when error is present, you'll need to add a condition to the hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (error !== '') {
    setShowModal(true);
  }
}, [error]);
```

Or more concise:

```
useEffect(() => setShowModal(Boolean(error)), [error])
```

Answer (score 1):

Ans 1:
Display the modal based on a check(condition)

```
useEffect(()=> {
  if(someHelperFunction(error))
    setShowModal(true)
}, [error])
```

Ans 2:
It runs when the component mounts because, initially when you use the `useState(initializer)`, It is changing the state from `undefined` to `initializer`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: You could do :

```
useEffect(()=>  if (!!error.error){ setShowModal(true)}, [error])
```

Q2: UseEffect runs every time a variable in the dependency array is changed, on the first render it runs once